# asyncio.as_completed() supposedly accepting `Iterable`, but crashes if input is `Generator`?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-typing

So, essentially, in Python 3.7 (as far as I know) if you try to do this,

```py
import asyncio


async def sleep():
    asyncio.sleep(1)


async def main():
    tasks = (sleep() for _ in range(5))
    for task in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        result = await task


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

It crashes with

```
TypeError: expect a list of futures, not generator
```

But the type hints clearly specify that it accepts an `Iterable`, which a `Generator` is.

If you turn `tasks` into a `list`, it works, of course, but... what am I missing?

And why would it be subjected to lists? I don't see why it should not allow generators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. The documentation here is not consistent with the actual behavior.

The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.as_completed) refers to the first argument as an *"iterable"*. And [typeshed as of today](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/asyncio/tasks.pyi#L53) also annotates the first argument with `Iterable[...]`.

However, in the CPython code for [`as_completed`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/asyncio/tasks.py#L558) the first argument is passed to [`coroutines.iscoroutine`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.11.1/Lib/asyncio/coroutines.py#L34), which checks, if it is an instance of [`types.GeneratorType`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/types.html#types.GeneratorType). Obviously, that is what it is, which has it return `True` and cause the `TypeError`.

And of course a generator is also an iterable. Which means the function does **not** in fact accept an iterable as the docs claim, but only a non-generator iterable.

Maybe someone else here can shine additional light on the background or thought process here. In any case, I would argue this is worth opening an issue over, if one addressing this does not exist yet.

**EDIT**: Apparently (and unsurprisingly) we were **not** the first ones to [notice this](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88342). Thanks to @KellyBundy for pointing it out.

Comment: Might be [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/88342)?

Comment: @KellyBundy Ah, nice. Thank you. I added it to the answer.